# Videogular2 ts imports not found

Tags: angular, ionic2, videogular

I'm trying to use [videogular2](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2) in an ionic2 application. So far i've executed `npm install videogular2 --save` and then tried to import anything from this package but none of the imports are found.

There are .d.ts files present for e.g. controls, but 6 days ago they have lost all their export statements. Deleting these .d.ts files would solve my problem, however I am not sure whether I'm missing something (i'm pretty much a typescript noob) or this is actually a bug in videogular2.

Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Install Typings CLI utility. 
`npm install typings --global`

Comment: didn't solve the problem. Also, aren't .d.ts files a native TypeScript feature?

Comment: I have done that in ionic2 so need help let me know